# changing two dropdownlists selected item from sql table but both get same selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdowns initializing from same sql table:

```
ddlETCsc1.Items.Clear();
ddlETCsc2.Items.Clear();
foreach (var PSiteContacts in ContactsAdapter.GetPSiteContacts(Cus_Id))
{
                var item = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem();    
                item.Text = PSiteContacts.name + " / " + PSiteContacts.phone;
                item.Value = PSiteContacts.name + " / " + PSiteContacts.phone;
                item.Attributes.Add("data-subtext", PSiteContacts.con_type);
                ddlETCsc1.Items.Add(item);
                ddlETCsc2.Items.Add(item);
 }
            ddlETCsc1.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Nothing Selected", "0"));
            ddlETCsc2.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Nothing Selected", ""));
```

I am changing there selected item from sql table columns SContact1 and Scontact2 these have different data but both get same selected item:

```
ddlETCsc1.SelectedValue = reader["SContact1"].ToString();
ddlETCsc2.SelectedValue = reader["SContact2"].ToString();
```

I can see by addiong breakpoints that ddlETCsc1 gets correct value first but when ddlETCsc2 value changes the ddlETCsc1 get same value as ddlETcsc2.

It works fine for first time(i have dropdowns in bootstrap modal) but when i adds new contact(button on modal that opens another modal to add contact and after adding opens previous modal and also initialize the dropdowns again with new values and fetch values from sql) then the selected value not work as expected
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because when you add `item` from your `ContactsAdapter` iteration, you refer to the same `item` (same `ListItem`) reference for each item in `ddlETCsc1` and `ddlETCsc2` (except for your "0" and "" later on). Try to change your code to:

```
ddlETCsc1.Items.Clear();
ddlETCsc2.Items.Clear();
foreach (var PSiteContacts in ContactsAdapter.GetPSiteContacts(Cus_Id))
{
    var item1 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem();    
    item1.Text = PSiteContacts.name + " / " + PSiteContacts.phone;
    item1.Value = PSiteContacts.name + " / " + PSiteContacts.phone;
    item1.Attributes.Add("data-subtext", PSiteContacts.con_type);
    ddlETCsc1.Items.Add(item1);

    var item2 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem();    
    item2.Text = PSiteContacts.name + " / " + PSiteContacts.phone;
    item2.Value = PSiteContacts.name + " / " + PSiteContacts.phone;
    item2.Attributes.Add("data-subtext", PSiteContacts.con_type);
    ddlETCsc2.Items.Add(item2);

 }
ddlETCsc1.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Nothing Selected", "0"));
ddlETCsc2.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Nothing Selected", ""));
```

To create **two** different references (albeit having the same initial value) for each item inserted in the `ddlETCsc1` and `ddlETCsc2`